# varchar(255) field or hash field?

Tags: mysql, performance, index, varchar, checksum

To consider a table with millions records and the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `foos` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `foo` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `foo_UNIQUE` (`foo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Ton of this query executes every second

```
SELECT 1 FROM foos WHERE foo=?
```

If no record finds, this query will be executed:

```
INSERT INTO foos(foo) VALUES(?)
```

The average length of `foo` less than 20. To optimize performance, a hashing field is considered to add with `md5(foo)` and drop the unique key.

```
ALTER TABLE foos DROP INDEX foo_UNIQUE;
ALTER TABLE foos ADD INDEX `foo_IDX` (`hash`);
```

And the query will be changed as:

```
SELECT 1 FROM foos WHERE hash=?
```

If no record finds, this query will be executed:

```
INSERT INTO foos(foo, hash) VALUES(?, ?)
```

The **Question** is:  Will the `SELECT` query run faster, since average length of `foo` less than 20 but hashing field length is always 32?

Comment: The difference in performance between the two `SELECTs` will be insignificant.  The avg length of the column will make a slight difference; however the various overheads will dominate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[In this answer, I assume using MD5 as hashing function]*

The answer is YES. Adding a "hash" field and querying it would run faster.

**Details:**
When indexing a `varchar(255)` field, although the average length is 20 char, each entry in the index will be saved in its full length, i.e. 255 char. Add to this that if you are using `utf8`, the entry length would be 255*3 bytes (plus the PK length).

When adding a hash field, make sure it has a fixed length (32 in case of MD5), and that the CHARSET is latin, i.e. 1 byte per char. In this case, the entry in the index will be 32 bytes (plus the PK length)

If you want to guarantee the uniqueness of `foo` field, it is recommended to add a unique index on the hash field (as opposed to a regular index)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO.  Today, Jehad's answer is wrong.  It may have been correct for some older version of MySQL and for some particular Engine (such as MEMORY before Version 8.0).

Today, Data and indexes are packed `VARCHAR`, they do not use the max length.  I verified with 5.6 with InnoDB and MyISAM.

That is, a `VARCHAR` column that averages 20 *bytes* will take only that much space.  However, if you experiment with this in InnoDB, the numbers will be quite confusing.  Here are some reasons why the sizes you get will be more than (20 * num-rows) in InnoDB:

- Overhead for each row (in data and in index): 20-30 bytes
- Overhead for each block: 10-20%
- Overhead for BTree block splits: 40%.  This *may* not be needed if you insert rows in order or if the Change Buffer effectively sorts for you.
- Allocation units:  At first, InnoDB allocates 16KB, but it quickly switches to 16*16KB, then 4MB.  So `SHOW TABLE STATUS` will show much bigger numbers for Data_length and Index_length, and the excess will not be included in Data_free.

A negative for Hashes:  They are notoriously "random".  That is, caching (the buffer_pool or key_buffer) becomes useless once the data (or index) grows much beyond the cache size.

If you are going to use an MD5 (or SHA1), pack it into `BINARY(16)` (or `(20)`) using `HEX()`. to save space.  Even doing that is not enough for me to recommend hash over an avg of 20 bytes in a `VARCHAR`.

Another tip:  Consider dropping the `AUTO_INCREMENT` and promoting the `VARCHAR` (or hash) to be the `PRIMARY KEY`.  In many (not all) situations, performance and space consumption both improve.

Comment: I agree with you here. On a personal note about formatting I would move the `pack it into BINARY(16) (or (20)) using HEX().` to the top. The rest of the question solves the X-Y problem. If you're going to store MD5s in MySQL that's the only right way.